# Is it possible to know when a user closes the google docs editing tab, so that i can download the file back to my application?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs, google-docs-api, google-drive-realtime-api

How can i know when a user has finished editing the file in google docs, so  that i can update my application with the changed file by downloading it from drive? a method  other than "domain verification" ..??

Answer (score 0):

Don't think so. You're only chance is asking the user if he's already closed the tab. You can however see the [modifiedTime](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/replies#resource).